# Vinogradov's "Elements of Number Theory", Ch1, Ex6: what is he talking about?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This is a very specific question tied to a very specific textbook.  I wish to clarify the meaning of an exercise question in said textbook.

Exercise 6 of Chapter 1 of the 2016 Dover reprint of Saul Kravetz's 1954 English translation of "Elements of Number Theory" by I.M. Vinogradov reads:

> Prove that there exist an infinite number of primes by counting the number of integers, not exceeding $N$, whose canonical decomposition does not contain prime numbers different from $p_1$, $p_2$, ..., $p_k$.

This makes it seem as though both $N$ and $\{p_1, p_2, ..., p_k\}$ should be arbitrary.  However, if both are arbitrary, then the numbers whose canonical decomposition includes only $\{p_1, p_2, ..., p_k\}$ could easily exhaust the integers not exceeding $N$.

I decided to let $\{p_1, p_2, ..., p_k\}$ be arbitrary, fixed $N = max(\{p_1, p_2, ..., p_k\})^2$, and worked from there, but I wonder if this is what Vinogradov had in mind.

A version of the textbook that appears identical to mine can be found [here](https://ia801408.us.archive.org/1/items/ElementsOfNumberTheory/Vinogradov-ElementsOfNumberTheory.pdf), and the exercise appears on page 19.  (Thanks to [miracle173](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11206/miracle173) for finding it.)

Comment: https://ia801408.us.archive.org/1/items/ElementsOfNumberTheory/Vinogradov-ElementsOfNumberTheory.pdf p 18

Comment: @miracle173 : nice find, but isn't it page 19?

Comment: yes, it is page 19

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume that there are only finitely many primes $p_1,\ldots, p_k$
Then there are at most 
$$\left(\frac{\log(N)}{\log(p_1)}+1\right) \cdot ... \cdot \left(\frac{\log(N)}{\log(p_k)}+1\right) \le  \left(2\frac{\log(N)}{\log(p_1)}\right) \cdot ... \cdot \left(2\frac{\log(N)}{\log(p_k)}\right) \tag{1}$$ 
numbers whose canonical decomposition includes only $\{p_1,\ldots, p_k\}$ that don't exceed $N$, if $N \ge \max\{p_1,\ldots,p_k\}$.

Therefore there are at most 
$$2^kt^k\frac{\log(N)}{\log(p_1)} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{\log(N)}{\log(p_k)} \tag{2}$$ numbers whose canonical decomposition includes only $\{p_1,\ldots, p_k\}$ that don't exceed $N^t$. But

$$\lim_{t \to \infty}2^kt^k\frac{\log(N)}{\log(p_1)} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{\log(N)}{\log(p_k)}/ N^t=0$$

Comment: Very nice. The first chapter of the book Prime Number Records lists about 23  different proofs of the infinity of primes, but not this one, which is new to me.

Comment: Nice.  How did you think to consider $N^t$?  Was it because the problem lends itself to logarithms, and $log(N^t)$ is malleable?

Comment: @JohnFogg: Yes,I tried $N^t$ because of the logarithms.

Comment: @JohnFogg I think the first estimate was wrong, I corrected this.

Comment: @miracle173: Your correction makes sense.  Is $\frac{log(N)}{log(p_i)} +1 \leq 2\frac{log(N)}{log(p_i)}$ because we assume $\frac{log(N)}{log(p_i)} \geq 1$, which is because the problem is silly if we consider primes larger than $N$?

Comment: @JohnFogg yes, you are right. I added this to the proof.

Answer (score 2):

> This is exactly the same answer  as https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2234659/11206 posted by of @user1952009. I made considerable changes in the presentation to try to make it more comprehensible to users that are not familiar with some notation known in number theory which were used by @user1952009.

If $P=\{p_1,\ldots,p_k\}$ is a finite  set of primes and
$$M(N):= \{n: ( n  \le N) \land ( \forall p \in P: p \nmid n)\} $$
is the set of number equal or less than $N$ that are not divided by a prime number, 
then we use the [inclusion-exclusion-principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to count $M(N)$ and get
$$\begin{align}
|M(N)|&=N \\
&-\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p_1}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p_2}\right\rfloor-\cdots-\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p_n}\right\rfloor\\
&+\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p_1p_2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p_1p_3}\right\rfloor+\cdots+\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p_{k-1}p_k}\right\rfloor\\
&-\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p_1p_2p_3}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p_1p_2p_4}\right\rfloor-\cdots-\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p_{k-2}p_{k-1}p_k}\right\rfloor\\
&\vdots\\
&(-1)^k\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p_1p_2\ldots p_k}\right\rfloor\\
\end{align}$$

Note that 
$$\pm\lfloor N/m \rfloor \ge \pm N/m-1$$
so that

$$\begin{align}
|M(N)|\ge& N -1 \\
&-\frac{N}{p_1}-1-\frac{N}{p_2}-1-\cdots-\frac{N}{p_n}-1\\
&+\frac{N}{p_1p_2}-1+\frac{N}{p_1p_3}-1+\cdots+\frac{N}{p_{k-1}p_k}-1\\
&-\frac{N}{p_1p_2p_3}-1-\frac{N}{p_1p_2p_4}-1-\cdots-\frac{N}{p_{k-2}p_{k-1}p_k}-1\\
&\vdots\\
&(-1)^k\frac{N}{p_1p_2\ldots p_k}-1\\
=&N\\
&-\frac{N}{p_1}-\frac{N}{p_2}-\cdots-\frac{N}{p_n}\\
&+\frac{N}{p_1p_2}+\frac{N}{p_1p_3}+\cdots+\frac{N}{p_{k-1}p_k}\\
&-\frac{N}{p_1p_2p_3}-\frac{N}{p_1p_2p_4}-\cdots-\frac{N}{p_{k-2}p_{k-1}p_k}\\
&\vdots\\
&(-1)^k\frac{N}{p_1p_2\ldots p_k}\\
&-2^k \\
=& N \prod_{i=1}^{k} (1-\frac{1}{p_i})-2^k
\end{align}$$

If $P$ contains all primes than $M(N)=\{1\}$ and therefore $|M(N)|=1$. But

$$\lim_{N \to +\infty}  \left(N \prod_{i=1}^{k} (1-\frac{1}{p_i})-2^k\right) =+\infty $$
and therefore if $P$ is finite we have 
$$\lim_{N \to +\infty} |M(N)| = +\infty$$
which contradicts $M(N)=\{1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $Q$ is a set of primes then $$\# \{ n  \le N, \forall q \in Q, q \nmid n\} = \sum_{m \in A_Q} \mu(m) \lfloor N/m \rfloor$$
where $A_Q$ is the set of squarefree integers whose prime factors are all in $Q$ and $\mu(m)$ is the Möbius function.

Note that $\lfloor N/m \rfloor = N/m+O(1)$ so that

$$\# \{ n  \le N, \forall q \in Q, q \nmid n\} = N\sum_{m \in A_Q} \frac{\mu(m)}{m}+\sum_{m \in A_Q}\mathcal{O}(1)$$ $$= N \prod_{q \in Q} (1-\frac{1}{q}) +  \mathcal{O}(2^{|Q|}) $$
and we get that $$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \# \{ n  \le N, \forall q \in Q, q \nmid n\} =\lim_{N \to \infty} N \prod_{q \in Q} (1-\frac{1}{q}) =\infty$$ so there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Mobius function, and I suspect that Vinogradov's intended solution was more elementary, but I will learn about the Mobius function so that I may understand this proof.

Comment: can you explain your first equation? I think it is based on the[Möbius formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Statement_of_the_formula), and that $f(n)=\# \{ n  \le N, \forall q \in Q, q \nmid n\}\# \{ n  \le N, \forall q \in Q, q \nmid n\}$, where $f$ is the notation from the wiki article. Can you explain what is $g$ and how do we get it?

Comment: @miracle173 Sure. We start with the $N$ integers $1\ldots N$, we remove $\lfloor N/2 \rfloor$ those divisible by $2$, then those $\lfloor N/3 \rfloor$ divisible by $3$, but we counted twice those divisible by $6$ so we add $\lfloor N/6 \rfloor$. This way $N-\lfloor N/2 \rfloor-\lfloor N/3 \rfloor+\lfloor N/6 \rfloor = \# \{ n  \le N, \forall q \in \{2,3\}, q \nmid n\} $. It works the same way $Q$ when contains more primes

Comment: when $Q$ contains more primes.

Comment: thank you, now I understand. You didn't apply the möbius inversion formula. I is simple and elegant but it seems that the usage of the Moebius function and the O notation irritates the readers.